# Typeerror: Missing one required argument in content

Tags: python, django

The code is below

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        record_name = request.POST.get('recordname')
        record_date = request.POST.get('recorddate')
        record_generate_by = request.POST.get('recordgenerateby')
        record_description = request.POST.get('recorddescription')
        record_file = request.FILES.get('recordfile')
        record_image = request.FILES.get('recordimage')
        fs = FileSystemStorage

        if record_file is None:
            record_file = 'No File'
        else:
            fs.save(record_file.name , record_file)


        if record_image is None:
            record_image = 'No Image'
        else:
            fs.save(record_file.name , record_file)
```

I used this API(FileSystemStorage) many times, but this time it shows error like this and already used this API in previous function and MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL is all set. The previous function stores file and image successfully, but this shows this kind of type error. Now what's the solution: 
The error is

```
       File "C:\Users\Mahad Akbar\PycharmProjects\FYP\Healthcare\myapp\views.py", line 754, in addnewRecord
       fs.save(record_file.name , record_file)
      TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'content'
       [06/Apr/2020 17:15:28] "POST /addnewRecord HTTP/1.1" 500 72349
```

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/storage/)?

`FileSystemStorage.save(name, content, max_length=None)
The content argument must be an instance of django.core.files.File or a file-like object that can be wrapped in File.`

Comment: Yes i read it and used it before. Its working perfectly but now showing this error

Answer (score 1):

`fs = FileSystemStorage` returns the **`class`** not an instance of `FileSystemStorage`. So in this case, `save` takes 3 arguments: `self`, `name` and `content`.

You need to instantiate `FileSystemStorage`: `fs = FileSystemStorage()`. Or better, use the `django.core.files.storage.default_storage` instance, which will work whatever storage you use after you deploy to production.

Also, when saving, you can't set content to a string ('No file'), you have to create a `File` object with that as content.

Comment: Thank you its working now, but for default file what is the better option?

Comment: Why do you want to store something if no file was submitted? Try finding a solution where you don't store it at all.